# Keep 2 Divs Centered with a Wrapper

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get the Main Content Area and the Sidebar colors to extend infinitely left and right as I did with the Header/Footer when you zoom out. But for whatever reason.. it's showing the background color (black) instead.

Here's the website in question: https://www.Answers.legal

```css
#main {
 width: 100%;
}

.content {
 width: 80%;
 background: #cccccc;
 height: 900px;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 position: relative;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 padding: 10px;
 float: left;
}

.sidebar {
 background: #424242;
 height: 900px;
 width: 20%;
 display: inline-block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 float: right;
 padding: 10px;
}

.wrapper {
    width: 1300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    background: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"><div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">
Welcome to Answers.Legal!
</div>
<?php $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
   $path .= "/common/sidebar.php";
   include_once($path); ?>
</div></div>
```

What can I do??

Thanks.

Comment: I updated the question; please read it again. I need the colors of the mainarea and sidebar to extend infinitely left and right like the colors of the header/footer do.

In other words, I never want the background color to show. Especially down at the bottom under the footer when you zoom out a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of your header, you have the background colors on outer elements that extend to the page width. With the main content, this is not the case. The challenge comes because you have a vertical column arrangement rather than horizontal rows.

You'll probably want to move the background color to `#main`, either as a vertically-repeating image or a CSS gradient. **[Here's a start](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/#cccccc+0,cccccc+60,424242+60,424242+100;Custom)** for the 2nd option.

Comment: Okay, fair enough. Makes sense. Thank you for the detailed response.

Now here's something I noticed and I'm guessing it's related..

Comment: On Google Chrome if I Inspect Element and navigate to #main.. it tells me that the height is 0Px... How come? Additionally, the #pagebottom is huge. Which is wrong. #Pagebottom should be the size of its contents which is 150px..

Comment: Divs don't take the height of their contents unless they have overflow set. It normally doesn't matter, but you can add `overflow: hidden` (or visible, or auto) to force it.

Comment: Hmm, okay. Adding overflow: hidden did in fact make Google Chrome show the correct dimensions. Just looks neater to me. 

I guess I'll just change the body's background color to something that looks decent as opposed to the black. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Add `float: left;` to `.content` and you should be fine.

Comment: Hey @arjabbar,

Now it works, but check out the website again.. The background is showing instead of extending the color of the div.. How come the header/footer background color extends infinitely but I can't get the main/sidebar color to do the same?

Comment: Also... Check out the HTML code..

There's 3 main sections: PageTop, Main, and PageBottom..

Why does it say that the dimenions of "Main" is 0px height??